# How to change only the shape of a toplevel window in GTK3+?

Tags: gtk, pygtk, gtk3

I use the function `gtk_widget_shape_combine_region` to set a shape for a GTK3+ window. However, this function will works for both top level and child windows. I just want to set the shape of the top level window and make some widgets outside the top level window area to be shown. For example, I set the shape of the top level window to be a circle, and I also want to show a button in the upper-right corner. I also try to use the GtkOverlay widget, put the button on top of it (upper-right corner), and pass the overlay widget to the `gtk_widget_shape_combine_region` function, but it won't work and print some error message: `gtk_widget_shape_combine_region: assertion`gtk_widget_get_has_window (widget)' failed`. Can I use some other container widgets? Is there any way to do this? Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: So which widget did you pass to shape_combine_region()? You shouldn't pass GtkOverlay, but the actual overlaid widget (possibly a button in your case).

Comment: If I pass in a button object, it print the same error message.

Comment: oh, I see GtkButton doesn't have a window either: you could try a GtkEventBox as the overlay widget and put the button inside the eventbox.